# 3011 error code access recordset vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is the code that I have worked over many many times, fix one error code3061, then another, now this.  ANY IDEAS WHY THIS ERROR IS HAPPENING, all objects spelled correctly?

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strForms As String
strForms = [Forms]![frmEnterResRecordset]![txtPhone]

MsgBox strForms

strSQL = "SELECT tblCustomer.IDCustomer, tblCustomer.PHONE, tblCustomer.LASTNAME, " & _
       "tblCustomer.FIRSTNAME, tblCustomer.NAME, tblCustomer.EMAIL " & _
       "FROM tblCustomer " & _
       "WHERE (((tblCustomer.PHONE) Like " & "*'" & strForms & "'*" & "));"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax near the Like operator.  The asterisks are outside the single quotes.  Try replacing it as follows:

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblCustomer.IDCustomer, tblCustomer.PHONE, tblCustomer.LASTNAME, " & _
   "tblCustomer.FIRSTNAME, tblCustomer.NAME, tblCustomer.EMAIL " & _
   "FROM tblCustomer " & _
   "WHERE (((tblCustomer.PHONE) Like " & "'*" & strForms & "*'" & "));"
```

Something I like to do when building dynamic SQL statements like this is to print it to the debug window with the following statement:

```
debug.print strSQL
```

It's easier to spot statements like:

```
Like *'my_entered_value'*
```

Comment: Thanks, one step closer, why is programming so much like gambling?  When you know you have it made, it just does not work the way you want and sucks you in for more

Comment: There comes an a-ha! moment where everything clicks and you'll find yourself thinking about things and approaching problems in a whole new way

Comment: YES, I worked it so many times, some many ways, got need to get away from it and needed  fresh eyes